# くだけた日本語 towards people you dislike?

Tags: politeness

Is this used ONLY amongst family and close friends or can you use it when you're trying to be rude?

For example if you use it on someone you don't like such as a stranger, could it be understood you're being rude on purpose (in other words unfriendly) or would they misunderstand and think you are on good terms?

Answer (score 7):

くだけた日本語 (casual Japanese), by definition, is used when people are trying to speak *friendly*, not rudely. If you want to keep a distance from someone, the normal way to do so is to keep using the polite language.

Many native speakers use くだけた日本語 even when they meet you for the first time. Generally speaking, elderly people or people living in rural areas tend to speak to you using くだけた日本語. And of course they don't want to be rude.

Of course くだけた日本語 would sound over-friendly or even rude depending on the situation. In very limited circumstances, it may be possible that someone uses it because they want to be rude on purpose. For example, one may use くだけた日本語 against their boss and show that they're upset.

Answer (score 3):

We ***do not*** use 「くだけた日本語」 with people we do not like because 「くだけた」 already includes the meaning of "friendly".

Unless one is a great actor or something, it would be extremely rare to see one using it outside of one's circle of friends and family.